# How to get rid of the inductive step while proving $n!+2$ is divisible by $2$ for all integers $n \ge 2$ by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, alternative-proof

> In the inductive step we assume that $k!+2$ is divisible by $2$. So
>   $k!+2=2r$ for some $r \in \Bbb Z$.
>
> To show that $(k+1)!+2$ is divisible by $2$.
>
> Consider $(k+1)!+2=(k+1)k!+2=k\cdot k!+ k!+2=k\cdot k!+2r.$

From here I can only think that since $k \ge 2$, the number $k!$ is even. Thus $k!=2s$ for some $r \in \Bbb Z$.

But I feel that by this logic, we don't need Principle of Mathematical Induction at all to solve this problem. Just apply this logic to the given statement.

So should I just write $k\cdot k!+2r=k\cdot k\cdot (k-1)\cdot \cdot \cdot 2\cdot 1+2r=2(k\cdot (k-1) \cdot \cdot \cdot 1 + r)$ and finish it off? are there any alternate ways?

Comment: Well, you need induction to show $2\mid k!$, perhaps. Nevertheless, for the problem at hand you are supposed to write $(k+1)!+2=(k+1)k!+2=(k+1)(k!+2)-2k=(k+1)2r-2k=2\cdot(\ldots)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So neat! +1

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in thinking that you don't really need induction here since the statement can be proven directly.

But if you want to use induction, try this:

$$\begin{align}
(k+1)!+2&=(k+1)k!+2\\
&=(k+1)(k!+2-2)+2\\
&=(k+1)(2r-2)+2\\
&=\ldots
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. This is best!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this problem directly as for $n\ge 2, n! $ is always even, then so is $n! +2$, and you are done.

If you want to use Principle of Mathematical Induction, then consider $(k+1)!$ which can be written as $(k+1) k!$ and substitute value of $k!$ from your induction hypothesis and you are done.

$(k+1)!= (k+1)k! = (k+1) (2r-2)$

Thus $(k+1)!+2= (k+1) (2r-2)+ 2$, which you can observe is divisible by $2$.

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}{}$. +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can follow
$$(k+1)!+2=(k+1)k!+2=k\cdot k!+k!+2=k(2r-2)+(2r-2)+2$$
and then the conclusion follows.